# How to remove horizontal scroll bar with remaining of all elements into the page?

Tags: html, css

I am begginer in web-developing. Nevertheless I hope for aid.

I have one layout that has to be performed as webpage by me. It has header, footer, main. There are one static image in main, one menu and content part in main. All elements situates in correct position if the user does not change the scale in own browser. There's one requirement: footer, header and menu must be painted with some colors, but all content of them must contain in rectangles width of which is 1000px. And don't forget about padding-left and padding-right 10px. If the scale is increased there's horizontal scrollbar and some elements occur in right side.

My requirements:

1. all components must fit in the first 100% of width. There must not be any need to scroll horizontally.
2. this vertical scrollbar must disappear

```css
 body
    {
        font-family: PT Sans;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 22px;
        color: grey;
        max-width: 100%;/*
        overflow-x: hidden;*/
     }

          #correct_width_header_footer
             {
              background-color: #D3D3D3;
              width: 100%;
              clear: left;
              }

      #internal_width
         {
         width: 1000px;
       margin: auto;
        padding-right: 10px;
         padding-left: 10px;
       }

      .header_sect
         {
             padding-bottom: 65px;
          padding-top: 65px;
            box-sizing: inherit;
          }

    #Left_header
    {
        height: 100px;
    }

    .phones
    {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    .menu_width
    {
       width: 100%;
       background-color: grey;
    }

    .menu
    {
       color: white;
       font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
       padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .menu a
    {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider
    {
       width: 100%;
       text-align: center;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .NewsBlock
    {
       width: 350px;
       color: white;
       background-color: grey;
       padding-left: 35px;
       padding-top: 20px;
       padding-bottom: 100px;
       margin-right: 60px;
       float: left;
    }

    .article_right
     {
       width: 510px;/*
     border: 1px solid;*/
     float: left;
     }

    .height_lowerSect
    {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    /*margin-bottom: 700px;*/
    }

    .footer_sect
    {
    /*background-color: black;*/
    position: relative;
    }

    #left_footer
    {
    float: left;
    }

    #left_footer li
    {
    list-style-type: none;
    }

    footer
    {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;/*
    margin-top: 65px;*/
    }

    .Underline li
    {
    text-decoration: underline;
    }

    .Underline
    {
    /*margin: auto;*/
    /*display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
    }

    .Last
    {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <header id="correct_width_header_footer">
        <section id="internal_width" class="header_sect">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" title="логтотип компании" id="Left_header" style="float: left;">
            <section class="phones">
                <br>+7(499)777-77-77</br>
                <br>+7(499)777-77-77</br>
            </section>
        </section>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="menu_width">
            <div id="internal_width" class="menu">
                <a>Главная</a>  |
                <a>Каталог</a>  |
                <a>Доставка и оплата</a>  |
                <a>Прайс-лист</a>  |
                <a>Контакты</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <img src="slider.jpg" class="slider" alt="slider">
        <section class="height_lowerSect" id="internal_width">
            <div class="NewsBlock">
                <h1>Новости</h1>
                <div>
                    <p>14 сентября 2013 г.
                    <br>Редизайн веб-сайта архитектурного бюро.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>14 сентября 2013 г.
                    <br>Раскрутка интернет-магазина декоративных стикеров и виниловых наклеек.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>14 сентября 2013 г.
                    <br>SEO-продвижение сайта поставщика дизельных генераторов. 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>14 сентября 2013 г.
                    <br>Поисковое продвижение веб-сайта поставщика гидрооборудывания.
                </div>
            </div>
            <section class="article_right">
                <h1>Компания "Пиксель-Плюс"</h1>
                <p>
                    Найстарішим з них є перший варіант. До початку вестернізації Японії у середині 19 століття ним позначали будь-який одяг. Ще у 16 столітті португальські місіонери-єзуїти повідомляли у звітах до Європи, що японці називають одяг словом «кімоно» (Kimono). Ця назва перекочувала у більшість іноземних мов, і в українську зокрема. Хоча у домодерній Японії «кімоно» було аналогом універсального поняття «одяг», у Європі та Америці воно стало асоціюватися саме з японським вбранням.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Наприкінці 19 століття у Японії збільшилась кількість тих, хто заходився носити західний стрій. Відмінність західного і японського костюму змушувала японців виокремити останній з загального поняття «кімоно». Виник неологізм для позначення традиційного одягу — «вафуку»[3] . До кінця Другої світової війни це слово стало основним для означення японського вбрання. Однак у післявоєнні часи, під впливом американського «розуміння» японської дійсності, універсальний термін «кімоно» почали застосовувати як один з синонімів «вафуку».
                </p>
                <p>
                    Відповідно, у сучасній японській мові «кімоно» отримало два значення. У широкому розумінні — це загальний термін для окреслення будь-якого одягу, а вузькому — різновид вафуку.
                </p>
            </section>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer id="correct_width_header_footer">
        <section id="internal_width" class="footer_sect">
            <div id="left_footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>2012-2013 ЗАО "Комания"</li>
                    <li>info@name.ru</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="left_footer" class="Underline">
                <ul>
                    <li>Главная</li>
                    <li>Каталог</li>
                    <li>Доставка и оплата</li>
                    <li>Прайс-лист</li>
                    <li>Контакты</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="left_footer" class="Last">
                <u>Разработка сайта</u> - 
                <br> компания "Пиксель-Плюс"
            </div>
        </section>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: If you set the `width: 1000px;` then what do you expect to happen when the browser is less than 1000px? Thats why it creates a scroll bar as you have imposed a static width

Comment: I could guess this, but what can I write down new to decide this issue? Anyway one of the requirements is contanent of header, menu and footer must be able to contain in area width 980px with padding 10px.

Comment: If I did not have to write this, what should I write now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding CSS media queries would really help in your case. I would create a media query where your 1000px width's will be set to 100% if the resolution becomes to small. Here's a quick example on how to approach it:

```
/* Screens that are less then 1020px wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 1020px) {
  #internal_width {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I think you also need to lose some of the other hardcode widths and make them percentage based or give them an automatic width by using flexbox in combination with flex-grow. This would make them smaller when the screen width is smaller. But it will keep the aspect ratio of your content. I would also remove the floats in your code. For example if you want to have more flexibility in the main content you can do it like this:

```
#internal_width {
    display: flex;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.NewsBlock {
    width: 350px;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 20px 0 100px 35px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.article_right {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

It set's the .NewsBlock content to 350px and the .article_right element next to it will just take up the space that it can have (until the combined value reaches 1000px). You can also apply this approach to your other elements as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to apply the same approach.